# INSERT in the query part of BigQuery, using google-api-php-client

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-client, google-api-php-client

I wanted to insert thousands of records in the database using INSERT command in php script , as it will easier to access, but https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference , this doesn't show the INSERT command that can be used while querying in php , like , 
$quert->setQuery("Insert into ... values...") , Have tried this in the Query Table of BigQuery web console, but it doesn't seem to work , Is there anyway to use setQuery() with some other command, to insert data ?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery doesn't support the INSERT command. You would need to create a load job. See https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/import#localimport for more information.

Comment: Jordan , that would be using java/python, I don't want to use neither of them. I want some php command, that will be similar to INSERT.

Comment: The PHP client has support for load jobs. Michael's answer below should work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jordan's answer, here's a snippet of code that should get you started using the Google BigQuery API and the [Google API PHP client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) for loading your own data into BigQuery programmatically. Note, this snippet simply spits out the raw API response of the load job, including the job Id to the screen - you'll have to add your own polling logic to check on the load job status.

*(We will be adding additional documentation about loading your own data, as well as more PHP samples soon).*

```
<?php

require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_BigqueryService.php";

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();

// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console to generate your
// oauth2_client_id, oauth2_client_secret, and to register your oauth2_redirect_uri.
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'));
$client->setClientId('XXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('XXXXXXXXX');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://YOURAPPLICATION/index.php');

// Instantiate a new BigQuery Client 
$bigqueryService = new Google_BigqueryService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>BigQuery API Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
  <div id='top'><h1>BigQuery API Sample</h1></div>
  <div id='main'>
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
      unset($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
      header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

        // Your project number, from the developers.google.com/console project you created
        // when signing up for BigQuery
        $project_number = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

        // Information about the destination table
        $destination_table = new Google_TableReference();
        $destination_table->setProjectId($project_number);
        $destination_table->setDatasetId('php_test');
        $destination_table->setTableId('my_new_table');

        // Information about the schema for your new table
        $schema_fields = array();
        $schema_fields[0] = new Google_TableFieldSchema();
        $schema_fields[0]->setName('first');
        $schema_fields[0]->setType('string');

        $schema_fields[1] = new Google_TableFieldSchema();
        $schema_fields[1]->setName('last');
        $schema_fields[1]->setType('string');        

        $destination_table_schema = new Google_TableSchema();
        $destination_table_schema->setFields($schema_fields);

        // Set the load configuration, including source file(s) and schema
        $load_configuration = new Google_JobConfigurationLoad();
        $load_configuration->setSourceUris(array('gs://YOUR_GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET/file.csv'));
        $load_configuration->setDestinationTable($destination_table);
        $load_configuration->setSchema($destination_table_schema);


        $job_configuration = new Google_JobConfiguration();
        $job_configuration->setLoad($load_configuration);

        $load_job = new Google_Job();
        $load_job->setKind('load');        
        $load_job->setConfiguration($job_configuration);

        $jobs = $bigqueryService->jobs;
        $response = $jobs->insert($project_number, $load_job);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($response);
        echo '</pre>';

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else {
      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Authorize Access to the BigQuery API</a>";
    }


?>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i have an already existing table , i just want to update or append my data to it , so , using from the "set the load config" will work fine right? Or should i set the schema for it again?

Comment: If you're appending to an existing table, you don't need to set the schema again.

Comment: @Michael Is it possible to do the same without using Google Cloud storage?

Comment: Yes - I haven't actually written this code yet, but you can create a multi-part mime post request in PHP that hits our direct upload endpoint (https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/jobs). Here's an example in Python: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatapostrequest

There's an example of this type of post request here: http://vedovini.net/2009/08/posting-multipart-form-data-using-php/